# save result of vtkDistancePolyDataFilter as .vtk

Tags: save, actor, vtk

I am working with vtkDistancePolyDataFilter and I want to save the result as a .vtk file.
The result is correct, I can display it with vtkRenderer. But I can't save it with a vtk writer, because they need an object as input.

How can I save my output? Maybe there is a way to convert a vktActor to an object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a vtkPolyDataWriter and set its input connection from the vtkDistancePolyDataFilter's output port. You don't need much more here.